# Redirection not happening after logout to the specified website in Azure AD using SimpleSAMLphp when multiple accounts present to be logged out

Tags: redirect, azure-active-directory, simplesamlphp

I have developed an SAML application which only uses Microsoft as IDP for successful login and logout of specific users. So after logout, I want Microsoft to redirect me to the website I have configured in the Logout URL of MyApplication in Azure Active Directory. The log-in functionality works everytime but when I logout in presence of only one Microsoft Signed-In account, it logouts perfectly and redirects me to the website I specified. I am facing the issue when I am asked to choose account to **logout from a set of accounts** (refer Image) of which when I select the configured account, it log me out perfectly but is **unable to redirect me** to my specified page. The **page gets stuck on "You signed out of your account It's a good idea to close all browser windows.**" (refer Image). ***Thus I want to be redirected to the specified page when I am asked to select an account while logging out.***

[Logout Issue Redirect Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQyC5.jpg)

[Logout Issue Redirect Image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/815EG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in this [library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/127).

Here are some alternatives.

- You can use silent logout.
- The post logout redirect isn't expected after calling logout. This could be a timing issue.
  You can achieve a 'clean' logout by opening a new window and calling logout from there. Then a user is left with an extra open window; but at least they've retained a view of the app and it hasn't lost state.